# no conflict on second time merging

Tags: git, git-merge

I a new learner of git.
I checked a file with "myfile.txt" with the content as

```
first commit in master.
```

committed the change in master branch with `git commit -a -m "first commit"`

In second step I created a branch from master `mysecondbranch` branch.
and add a second line.

```
first commit in master.
**second commit in mysecondbranch.**
```

again commiting the changes in `mysecondbranch`

now switching back to `master` branch. and added new content as

```
frst commit in master.
**second commit in newbranch.**
```

and commited the changes to master branch.

next I want to merge the changes in mysecondbranch using the command as

```
git merge mysecondbranch
```

this time as expected it there is a  conflict while merging..

the problem starts here I discard the change of merge using

```
git reset HEAD myfile
```

try the merge again But I am surprised this time there is no conflict and there is no result of    `git diff`

I am getting the error as 
**`fatal: commit your changes before you can merge.`**

Answer (score 2):

When you issue

```
git reset HEAD myfile
```

you don't discard the changes of the merge. Do a

```
git status
```

after the reset and you'll see that you have unstaged changes. If you want to really discard the changes from the merge do a

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

after the call to merge.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
git reset --hard master
```

instead of

```
git reset HEAD myfile
```

to discard the changes